# SQL: Calculate based on existence of consecutive records

Tags: sql-server

I'm building out a bonus that calculates eligibility of our sales team based on a number of criteria, with the most challenging part being the criterion of achieving an aggregate value in a consecutive 3-month period.

Here's what I have so far (among other criteria) for calculating this bonus:

```
select customer
    ,salesperson
    ,year
    ,month
    ,gm
    ,Appearance_Count
    ,case
        when appearance_count between 1 and 6 then 'Y' end as 'First 6'
    ,case
        when gm >= 150 then 'Y' end as 'Monthly Min'
from basedata
```

And the result set thus far:

[image]

- The month represents the period (which is just any sale within a given month)
- The gm is the amount
- and I created the appearance_count as a counter to represent how many months the customer has existed.
- In that first CASE statement, the AC defining between 1 and 6 indicates that the bonus is only eligible for the customer that exists with us within the first 6 months that they are our customer.
- The second CASE indicates that there must be a minimum GM of 150 per month to activate eligibility.

So where I'm struggling is I also need to factor in that there needs to be a total of 2400 GM for any 3-month consecutive period (within the 6 month window). What's the easiest way to figure the consecutive 3 month period?

---

**UPDATE 1:** Here is an example of what I'm hoping to see.

```
customer  salesperson   yr  mon gm      AC   1st 6  Mon/Min  3-mo-consec
3D PAVING   Ryan      2019  8   1771.67    1    Y     Y         N
3D PAVING   Ryan      2019  9   1169.19    2    Y     Y         N
3D PAVING   Ryan      2019  10  1132.07    3    Y     Y         Y
3D PAVING   Ryan      2019  11  585.99     4    Y     Y         N
```

Comment: can a year-month be missing for a customer? or will they just have a row with 0 in it?

Comment: I believe it's possible for a row to be missing. For instance, the 3D Paving customer could have no sales in December, but sales in January, so we'd see it ordered as going from 11/2019 to 1/2020.

Comment: But the December should have sales 0, You should have a month table and do a left join with customer sales. Missing rows shouldnt happen or the whole 3 consecutive months will fail

Comment: Surely there's a way to use the appearance count in a way that uses counting based on the integer, rather than the existence of the consecutive records? I have one example where a customer had sales in August, no sales in Sept, and sales in October. Couldn't the no sales in Sept be implied somehow as a zero?

Comment: **Consumable** sample data (`text` not a n image) and expected results will greatly help us help you.

Comment: In the expected results, why is the last `3-mo-consec` calculated as 'N'?  It seems to also have a total of 2400 GM for any 3-month consecutive period within a 6 month window?

Comment: The last one is N because once the bonus becomes eligible, it occurs once and is no longer able to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially do this with a chain of self-joins, but it won't be very fast for a large amount of data because it requires some arithmetic in JOIN conditions which means that indexes can't be used. If that's not a problem (which I'm guessing it's not if you're creating a report to be generated every once in a while), the following query should help.

`a`, `b`, and `c` represent the first, second, and third months in your 3 consecutive months respectively. You join each row to the next on the condition that it is the next month in the same year, or the first row is December in year X and the second row is January in year X + 1. You can then sum the `gm` for each of the joined records and check it against your boundary of 2400.

```
SELECT WHEN a.gm + b.gm + c.gm > 2400 THEN 'Y' END AS three_month_aggregate
FROM basedata a
INNER JOIN basedata b
    ON a.customer = b.customer
    AND a.salesperson = b.salesperson
    AND (
        (a.year = b.year AND a.month = b.month - 1)
        OR (a.year = b.year - 1 AND a.month = 12 AND b.month = 1)
    )
INNER JOIN basedata c
    ON b.customer = c.customer
    AND b.salesperson = c.salesperson
    AND (
        (b.year = c.year AND b.month = c.month - 1)
        OR (b.year = c.year - 1 AND b.month = 12 AND c.month = 1)
    )
```

This only fetches the three_month_aggregate condition, so you'll have to either run it separately or JOIN the results in to your original query. You could do that like this:

```
SELECT customer
    ,salesperson
    ,year
    ,month
    ,gm
    ,Appearance_Count
    ,CASE
        WHEN appearance_count BETWEEN 1 AND 6 THEN 'Y' END AS 'First 6'
    ,CASE
        WHEN gm >= 150 THEN 'Y' END AS 'Monthly Min'
    ,tma.three_month_aggregate AS 'Three Month Aggregate'
FROM basedata i
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT WHEN a.gm + b.gm + c.gm > 2400 THEN 'Y' END AS three_month_aggregate
    FROM basedata a
    INNER JOIN basedata b
        ON a.customer = b.customer
        AND a.salesperson = b.salesperson
        AND (
            (a.year = b.year AND a.month = b.month - 1)
            OR (a.year = b.year - 1 AND a.month = 12 AND b.month = 1)
        )
    INNER JOIN basedata c
        ON b.customer = c.customer
        AND b.salesperson = c.salesperson
        AND (
            (b.year = c.year AND b.month = c.month - 1)
            OR (b.year = c.year - 1 AND b.month = 12 AND c.month = 1)
        )
) tma ON (
    (i.customer = a.customer AND i.salesperson = a.salesperson)
    OR (i.customer = b.customer AND i.salesperson = b.salesperson)
    OR (i.customer = c.customer AND i.salesperson = c.salesperson)
)
```

**EDIT** - If you only want the 'Y' to appear for one of the three months' records, you can remove the corresponding JOIN condition at the end of the query. I specifically designed it so that it would give a 'Y' for every month that was part of the three consecutive months, but if you only want a 'Y' for the first month in the list for example you can change the final JOIN condition in the query to this:

```
) tma ON (
    (i.customer = a.customer AND i.salesperson = a.salesperson)
    # removed JOIN to b and c, the second and third months in the chain
)
```

Note: this does mean that only that month will now appear in your overall results. If you still want all the months to appear, use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN for joining against the `tma` subquery.

Comment: The first thing I'm wondering about is in the first query, why do you have the parts where a.month = 12 AND b.month = 1? I'm not understanding the logic of that join condition.

Comment: You could cursor though the results thus far and with a few IFs determine if the conditions are met and insert into a temp table.  Once outside the cursor, sikmply select from the temp table.

Comment: The reason for that particular condition (`(a.year = b.year - 1 AND a.month = 12 AND b.month = 1)`) is to capture the case where your consecutive three months spans over two years, for example if you had the months Dec 2018, Jan 2019, Feb 2019, or the months Nov 2017, Dec 2017, Jan 2018. The 12 represents December and the 1 represents January.

Comment: I made an edit to your solution to show the results I got, but looks like it's being held up by peer review before you can see it. Is that to be reviewed by you? If not, let me know and I'll post as second update to my original question.

Comment: I will edit my answer to address the issue you raised in your edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you misunderstood. The initial query is where the issue is, the one that fetches the three_month_aggregate condition. It is not correctly defining the eligible months. In my original question, under UPDATE 1, I have an example of expected/intended results. Is it possible to get those results with any slight mods to this query you wrote? Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Also, as for the join condition previously mentioned, shouldn't they be reversed? If b.year - 1 is the previous year, shouldn't b.month be 12?

Comment: So what you want essentially is the first month that the aggregate `gm` builds up to over 2500? And then after that, the aggregate should essentially reset back to 0? With respect to the join condition, I think that it's correct the way it is - if a.month = b.month -1, a's month is one month before b's month. Therefore, a is the earlier one chronologically.

Comment: If that is the case, I think the closest you can get with this query is to LEFT JOIN against 'c' rather than 'a'. It will give a Y for every month where the last two month's gm + the current month's gm adds up to over 2500, rather than resetting after you see a Y.

Comment: "So what you want essentially is the first month that the aggregate gm builds up to over 2500? And then after that, the aggregate should essentially reset back to 0?" - Yes.And you're right about the join condition, my bad.